# Problema con bucle do while dentro de un for

Tags: java

tengo una un problema que no consigo solucionar con una bucles en java para un ejercicio de clase.
Necesito hacer un programa que me formule 10 preguntas de tablas de multiplicar aleatorias. Al final de las 10 preguntas me tiene que mostrar las preguntas que han sido acertadas a la primera. En caso de que una pregunta no se acierte a la primera, debe mostrar la tabla del numero fallado y, a continuación, reformular la pregunta.

El fallo que tengo es que dentro del `for` de las 10 preguntas tengo un `if -else`para las preguntas correctas y dentro del else el `do-while` para reformular las preguntas.
El problema es el siguiente: cuando fallo la pregunta, el programa la reformula como debe de hacer pero si introduzco la respuesta correcta, el bucle `do-while`
me cierra el `for` y deja de hacer preguntas.
Dejo por aquí el código.

```
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
Tablas operacion=new Tablas();


int pregunta = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, operacion.getNumeroPregunta()+"\n"+operacion.multiplicacion()));
    if (pregunta == operacion.resultado()) {
        Tablas.comprobadorPreguntas(true);
    }
    else {
        do {
        String salida="";
        for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            salida+=operacion.getMultiplicando() + "x"+i+"=" + (operacion.getMultiplicando() * i) + "\n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, salida);
        pregunta = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, operacion.getNumeroPregunta()+"\n"+operacion.multiplicacion()));
    } while(pregunta != operacion.resultado());
        Tablas.comprobadorPreguntas(false);
}
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Preguntas acertadas a la primera: "+Tablas.getContador());
```

Aquí dejo también los pastebin con las clases del programa y los métodos.
Agradecería también sugerencias para mejorar el código.

Programa > https://pastebin.com/imAQBuRX

Métodos > https://pastebin.com/GJdyrnRv

Muchas gracias

Comment: Buenas. Es posible que tu problema sea que para ambos bucles for estás usando la misma variable índice 'i'?

Answer (score 0):

Dado que es una tarea escolar y que tu objetivo es aprender, **te voy a dejar un ejemplo de cómo encontrar índices aleatorios**, no me voy a meter con do-while, ni while, **sólo** con los números **aleatorios** o **random**.

**Copiá** y **pegá** el código en una clase que se llame "**Panel**" y dale "**Run as java application**", luego **analizá** lo que pasa **por consola** **cada vez** que le das **repetidas veces** a "**Run as java application**", fijate si te sirve para tu programa de preguntas aleatorias.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Panel {

    public void arrayListRandom() {

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list = Arrays.asList("Nombre?", "Apellido?", "Edad?", "Cancion?", "Estudios?");

            Random random = new Random();
            Integer entero = random.nextInt(list.size());

            System.out.println(entero);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panel p = new Panel();
       p.arrayListRandom();
    }

}
```

Por cada vez que corrés el programa la consola imprime un entero diferente, tomando como tamaño máximo dentro del cual se mueve el tamaño máximo del ArrayList<>, también se puede hacer más simple, utilizando Arrays o vectores simples.

El resultado es absolutamente el mismo, para empezar te recomiendo que los utilices por sobre cualquier tipo de Colleción.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Panel {

    public void arrayListRandom() {

        String[] list = { "Nombre?", "Apellido?", "Edad?", "Cancion?", "Estudios?" };

        Random random = new Random();
        Integer entero = random.nextInt(list.length);

        System.out.println(entero);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.arrayListRandom();
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo. El profesor nos prohibió el uso de arrays en este ejercicio ya que estamos empezando con los fundamentos más básicos y ahora mismo necesito entender por qué un bucle cierra al otro.

Comment: Bueno seguí practicando que ya te va a salir, tené ése código que te dejé para cuando necesites realizar aleatoridad de algo. Abrazos